# Removing white spaces between words shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

Need to remove leading whitespaces just between colon and the word as shown below. in bash or korn shell scipt

input:

```
TEST="test":"           94 days (8193578 seconds)"
```

output:

```
"test":"94 days (8193578 seconds)"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works as you intend

```
TEST=$(echo ${TEST} | sed -e 's/:"[[:space:]]*/:"/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest possible solution:
`echo ${TEST//  /}`

It just removes all double-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

simple using sed:

```
TEST=$(echo ${TEST} | sed -e 's/:" *//')
```